# Gnuplot axis ranges format

Tags: range, gnuplot, axis

I'm trying to plot data out of a CSV file, and my xrange is not linear - it rises from 0.5 to 1.2, then down to 0.1 as the dataset progresses. Gnuplot is ranging the data from 0.1 to 1.2 ascending, and I need to tell it to just take the data as it reads it. How do I do that? the data is a temperature plot against a varying water flow rate...

Thanks!

Here's a sample of my data to be plotted, sorry it's long:

0.558    34.327

0.698    34.429

1.264    34.577

1.258    34.690

1.252    34.864

1.274    35.010

1.271    35.097

1.286    38.223

1.306    38.186

1.291    38.114

1.288    38.100

1.294    38.049

1.288    38.005

1.297    37.467

1.297    37.464

1.299    37.437

1.298    37.399

1.281    37.406

0.606    37.456

0.607    37.449

0.601    37.483

0.594    37.495

0.594    37.587

0.607    37.625

0.607    37.737

0.596    37.798

0.599    37.918

0.334    38.015

0.348    38.073

0.355    38.171

0.345    38.259

0.348    38.386

0.142    39.230

0.137    39.305

0.126    39.374

0.115    39.371

0.131    39.423

0.132    39.369

Further into this data, the x and y variables will increment AND decrement as it goes on. I just need the X axis to show up as it's read from the file. I have attached an image of the excel generated graph that I'm trying to replace, and the gnuplot version (only one plot line) for comparison.

[image: Excel Plot]

[image: Gnu Plot]

[image: "Fixed" Gnuplot]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set xtics rotate by -90
plot "-" using 0:2:xtic(1) with lines
0.558 34.327
0.698 34.429
1.264 34.577
1.258 34.690
1.252 34.864
1.274 35.010
1.271 35.097
1.286 38.223
1.306 38.186
1.291 38.114
1.288 38.100
1.294 38.049
1.288 38.005
1.297 37.467
1.297 37.464
1.299 37.437
1.298 37.399
1.281 37.406
0.606 37.456
0.607 37.449
0.601 37.483
0.594 37.495
0.594 37.587
0.607 37.625
0.607 37.737
0.596 37.798
0.599 37.918
0.334 38.015
0.348 38.073
0.355 38.171
0.345 38.259
0.348 38.386
0.142 39.230
0.137 39.305
0.126 39.374
0.115 39.371
0.131 39.423
0.132 39.369
EOF
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, not sure what w and lp are... this is my plot command:

plot 'c:\users\tsc\desktop\csv\VCF thermal data.csv' using 4:5 linecolor rgb "red" with lines

it plots, but because my x range is increments and decrements as you jump from datapoint to datapioint, my plot looks wrong. The excel version looks correct, but excel is a problem to get working right... thus using gnu.

Comment: > u 2 w lp. I changed the answer.

Comment: hmmm, not sure I follow - if I plot using the plot command I posted above, and change "with lines" to "with line points", I get 2 errors:

**warning: No pointsize specifier allowed, here**

and 

**duplicated or contradicting arguments in plot options** 

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Ok, I figured that out, but the graph is still wrong. Did you see the edit I made above?

I'm not sure I'm asking correctly, but I'm trying to get gnuplot to plot the points in a csv file as they appear in the file. Right now, my x axis shows up as "0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1.0" when it should show up as "0.5, .2, .3, .4, .6, .2, .3, .1, .7" etc.

Comment: I am confused. I see no columns in you data file.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure why. when I posted them they showed up in the edit in two columns, not sure why not after I posted them... 

Ok, I'll illustrate with a set of numbers: X={1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 2, 3, 1, 6, 9} and Y={2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6}. So when I graph this with gnuplot, it arranges the X values in ascending or descending order. I want it to be laid out in the graph in the order it appears in the set. so instead of seeing "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7," as the X axis, I'll instead see "1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 2, 3, 1, 6, 9" as it appears in the set. That's what I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: I could plot only with points, but I have over 256,000 points to plot... that's a lot of work to set up. Thus the CSV file exported from excel. I just want to tell gnuplot to not plot the numbers in ascending or descending order, but one at a time as it reads them. Or maybe a better way to say it would be to not have a linear x range, but a random one.

Comment: I think you have three options: "Y vs. X", "Y vs. N" or "X vs. N" where N is a consequent number of point in the dataset. The corresponding gnuplot commands  are "<..> using 1:2", "<..> using 0:2" and "<..> using 0:1".

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you 100%... the two columns I posted are actually X,Y columns 4 and 5 in my csv file. so my assumption would be to plot as such: plot "data.file" using 4:5 with lines. which should plot Y vs X, and it does. But the graph shows the value of X as increasing instead of as random across the graph as it appears in the data.

Comment: If there was a way to send you a picture of what I'm talking about I would happily do so, just not seeing anything here that allows me to attach...

Comment: You can try http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: My interpretation is that you want "Y vs X" plot and change the order
of points on X axis which is not possible because X position is fixed
for every point. But I am obviously misunderstand something.

Comment: Ok, I attached photos. Look at the x axis of the excel plot - notice that it plots each X,Y pair in order as it reads them from the file, where as Gnuplot plots Y vs X in order of X value, lowest to highest.

Comment: My results are posted in the photos above. Still no.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32584/discussion-between-jedi-engineer-and-slitvinov)